# What ifram To Be used For Embedding Youtube Videos Dynamically Into The Website?

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have used

```
<iframe width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

this iframe to embed my Youtube video on website.

But my custom URL includes /c/ instead of /user/ [Custom URL - https://www.youtube.com/c/Coingraph]. Hence this iframe is not working.

Please let me know which iframe is to be used for the custom URL that includes /c/ and not /user/.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/c/Coingraph is not working for me, YouTube just responds with a 404 for that.

Comment: Hi, if you can provide me with the iframe that can be used for /c/ in the custom URL.... Then that would be of great help!

Comment: No, because I don’t know what exactly you want here. As I said, https://www.youtube.com/c/Coingraph does not even work to begin with. So what _exactly_ would be the URL you want to embed?